# How to combine ply of multiple views into a single object of 360 degree view

Tags: view, cloud, point, pcl, ply-file-format

I have 8 ply files for a single object but each of different views. I need to integrate all those scenes and form 360 degree mesh. Is there a technique in pcl to intergrate all those scenes. Can icp be used in integrating scenes. If so it will be useful if anyone provide sample code that integrate it.

I need to integrate different views of a single scene.I tried icp but i was not able to integrate it. I am not sure how source and target is fixed and how it will be aligned. Can icp used for integrating scenes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called registration. The PCL tutorials may be a good starting point for you: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/#registration
Yes, ICP is one possible method for this. Whether it will succeed depends on the parameters you choose, the object itself, and how good the starting guess is you give to ICP.

Comment: I have two different views. One is front view and the other is profile view(side view). In that case I tried to use icp. But it is just aligning and resulting only one cloud and not merging it. Is there any way to integrate it I even tried to concatenate the result of icp with view 1. But merging was not accurate.

Comment: Then what do you mean exactly with "integrate"? And how was "merging not accurate"? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Integrate in my case is I need to combine front view and side view. So when combining I was not able to perform it. So if there is any algorithm to work on in order to achieve end goal

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code. BUt it does not integrate two different views.

```
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZRGB> icp;
icp.setMaximumIterations(500);
icp.setInputSource(mls_points_with_normals);
icp.setInputTarget(mls_points_with_normals2);
// icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance (0.05);
icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon(1);
icp.setTransformationEpsilon(1);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr aligned_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
icp.align(*aligned_cloud);

Eigen::Matrix4f transformation_matrix = icp.getFinalTransformation();
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr transformed_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
pcl::transformPointCloud(*mls_points_with_normals, *transformed_cloud, transformation_matrix);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr integrated_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
*integrated_cloud = *transformed_cloud + *mls_points_with_normals2;
```